# Apache camel route from cxfrs to activemq queue issue

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, cxf, activemq-classic

I have implemented restful webservice with the help of spring+cxf:rsServer.

```
 <cxf:rsServer id="cxfContainer" address="/">
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="restService"/>
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
    <cxf:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />   <!--  use .json to get data in JSON format -->
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />     <!-- use .xml to get data in XML format -->
        </cxf:extensionMappings>
        <cxf:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="jaxbXmlProvider" />
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsServer>
```

now i want to route xml/json input  on webservice to activemq.
so i added camelContext like

```
  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
             <route>
            <from uri="cxfrs:bean:cxfContainer"/>
           <choice>
                <when>

                    <camel:xpath>/PlayerType/playerId= '007'</camel:xpath>
                    <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:RESTFULL.queue"/>           
                </when>
                 <otherwise>
                    <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:DefaultQueue"/>
                 </otherwise>               
            </choice>
             </route>     

    </camelContext>
```

XML input File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PlayerType xmlns="http://benchresources.in/cdm/Player">
    <playerId>007</playerId>
    <name>abcd</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <matches>70</matches>
</PlayerType>
```

Its throws following error.

```
unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList 
to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [in.benchresources.cdm.player.PlayerType@d792a03] while invoking public java.lang.String com.apache.cxf.xml.json.service.Playe
rServiceImpl.createOrSaveNewPLayerInfo(in.benchresources.cdm.player.PlayerType) with params [in.benchresources.cdm.player.PlayerType@d792a03].
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.Mes
sageContentsList to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [in.benchresources.cdm.player.PlayerType@d792a03]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem many times when dealing with Camel's CXF endpoint. Essentially when you get a response from your cxfrs bean the cxf response is encapsulated in a MessageContentsList(essentially an arraylist). There error you're getting is because you're trying to a MessageContentsList object into org.w3c.dom.Document which throws this error.

You can get around this by adding a processor right after your cxfrs bean that pulls the response out of the MessageContentsList and sets it as the body of the message. Something like this:

```
process(Exchange e){
    MessageContentsList list = (MyObject) e.getIn().getBody();
    MyObject obj = list.get(0);
    e.getIn().setBody(obj);
}
```

Comment: thanks David thats really helps me. i would like to ask one more favor from you about xpath is not execute correctly.

Comment: resolved by adding namespace within camelcontext param. Thanks again